# Confused about SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-3.5, sqldatasource, dataview

in my C# code, I use a connection string like this:

```
connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myconnectionstring"])
```

which works fine.

I'm now trying to use the `<asp:SqlDataSource` control, but I can't seem to use the above connection string in the control like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"   
ConnectionString="<%$ ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myconnectionstring"] %>"   
SelectCommand="SELECT * from table1"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I get an error saying:

> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not code you run there but a [placeholder:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.connectionstring) that basically tells the DataSource 'look in the config file for a configuration block called ConnectionStrings and if you find it take the value from the element with the key myconnectionstring'

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"    
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myconnectionstring%>"    
SelectCommand="SELECT * from table1"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

remember to add your connectionstring the app.config section ConnectionStrings,

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="myconnectionstring" connectionString="server=localhost;database=Northwind;user=north;password=north;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

specially because [you want to keep them safe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178372%28v=vs.90%29)

Comment: Thanks, got it working using `AppSettings:myconnectionstring`.